# Why is Y constant on the left side of the equation : Y̅=C(Y̅–T̅)+I(r)+G̅, of the Mundell Fleming model?

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, economic-growth

Since I(r) is not constant, how could Y be constant on the left side of the equation of the goods market equilibrium - IS curve function?

Thank you!

Ps: I don't know where I should write function, or equation, so sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

In *the* Mundel Fleming model it is not constant. You must be working with some simplified version of Mundel Fleming model.

If Y is held fixed that means something else has to change when I changes. In your example, only other thing that is not fixed is the consumption function $C(.)$ so when I increases something must happen there. Maybe marginal propensity to consume decreases or autonomous consumption shrinks. The source of the model should explain its assumptions.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! So, in this case I(r) is constant? In addition, how can C(.) not be constant, when it depends on Y̅ and T̅, which are both constant variables C(Y̅–T̅)? Thanks!

Comment: C(.) is a function, for example C(Y-T) could look like $C=c_0+ c_1(Y-T)$ assuming linear consumption function. The parameters $c_0$ and $c_1$ could change if you allow them to be for the sake of the problems variables.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @student you are welcome if the above answer answered your question consider accepting it

Comment: How do I accept it?

Comment: @student you can click on the tick below upvote button. You should also consider doing that for other people who answered your questions

Comment: Hi muflon, do you have any idea why I can' post with this account? Thanks.

Comment: @student i am not sure what you mean? Please make a post about it on our meta page and describe the problem in detail

Comment: I meant that I can't ask questions with this account.

Comment: @student hi please post about it on our meta site

Comment: How? Thank you very much!

Comment: @student even if you can’t post here you should be able to post on the economics.meta stack exchange

Comment: Okay, sorry and thanks a lot!!!